# How to clear knockout observable array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, observable

I'm trying to reset a knockout observable array in my view model to contain nothing, yet I'm being stonewalled at every turn. When it is defined, I set it empty:

```
self.currentPeople = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Yet if I try to alter it down the page:

```
self.currentPeople.removeAll();
```

I get the exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Even if I do a safe check to see if it exists and then set it:

```
 if (self.currentPeople ) {
       self.currentPeople.removeAll();
 } else {
       self.currentPeople = ko.observableArray([]);
 }
```

I still receive the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your viewmodel, or at least enough of it to get the full context of where `currentPeople` is being defined and used?

Comment: ... or at least the stack trace of the exception and appropriate code

Answer (score 1):

If by contain nothing and clear array you mean contain an empty array you simply do:

```
self.currentPeople([]);
```

On a side note, testing with

```
if(someObservable)
```

Will always return true, to test if it contains anything use "someObservable()". That will get the observables value instead of the wrapper.
I am confused though by how self.currentPeople.removeAll() throws an error, could you post more of your code if the above solution does not work out for you, and clarify what you need?

I am aware half of this answer should be a comment but I do not have the rep to do so yet.

Answer (score -1):

You need to 'de-reference' your observable array by saying `self.currentPeople().removeAll()`

Comment: [No you don't](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#remove-and-removeall), and in fact if you work on the underlying array in this way, knockout won't see the change you make either.